# Extract NodeJS Response into HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, stripe-payments

I want to take this request on NodeJS

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_AJKebDsM6QFiK8VpJ06Vq1M1";

stripe.balance.retrieve(function(err, balance) {
// asynchronously called
});
```

which an example response is

```
{
  "pending": [
{
  "amount": 0,
  "currency": "usd"
}
 ],
 "available": [
{
  "amount": 0,
  "currency": "usd"
}
],
 "livemode": false,
"object": "balance"
}
```

and extract the balance information to place it into an HTML label.

How would I go about doing this? Can I pass the `response` to Angular and then link that to HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have that being served in a route (something like `/balance`) and then have your angular app consuming it:

If you're using express as your web framework, here's an example (from the top of my head - not tested):

```
app.get('/balance', function (request, response) {
  stripe.balance.retrieve(function(err, balance) {
    response.send(balance);
  });
});
```

and here your angular app:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('BalanceController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/balance').then(function (response) {
    $scope.balance = response.data;
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, will give check when time allows.

Comment: Tried that, but it's returning an error for the `app.get` in the Node file. This is the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined` Why would this be?

Comment: Yes, do I set `var app = express();`?

Comment: Well, yes... How are you running your server? I assume you have something like an entry point (`index.js` or `server.js`…) and run it like `node index.js` or `node server.js`. And its content, at a minimum, should be `var express = require('express'); var app = express(); app.listen(3000 /*or some other port*/);` Then, before listening you'd add the code from my answer.

Comment: I'm doing that, but now it is saying `required` is undefined. Any simple solutions?

Comment: It is not `required`, but `require` – watch out for the last `d`.

Comment: I made a typo. It was `require`. I think this has to do with NodeJS on the client-side? Any easy fix?

Comment: Oh, no no.. You won't be able to do that entirely from the client (unless you're using stripe's client side lib). The first part of my answer has to run in the server side, the second part is on the client. -- If stripe's client side lib provides you a way to fetch balance, the way to make it work with angular is something like `$scope.$apply(function() { $scope.balance = response; });`. The reason why you have to wrap it in a `$apply` callback is that stripe lives outside of angular's lifecycle, and you have to let it know something has changed.

Comment: So why does this not work? Aren't I running Node server-side? `var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080);
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/balance', function (request, response) {
  stripe.balance.retrieve(function(err, balance) {
    response.send(balance);
  });
});` AND `angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('BalanceController', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/balance').then(function (response) {
    $scope.balance = response.data;
  });
});`

Comment: You're mixing up `connect` and `express`. Try not using connect directly:

`var express = require('express');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname));
app.get('/balance', function (request, response) {
  stripe.balance.retrieve(function(err, balance) {
    response.send(balance);
  });
});
app.listen(8080);`

Comment: I'll setup a [http://runnable.com/](http://runnable.com/) instance to demonstrate it as soon as get some time.

Comment: Here: [http://runnable.com/U6omaGEBWORSfUKE/stripe-example-for-node-js-and-hello-world](http://runnable.com/U6omaGEBWORSfUKE/stripe-example-for-node-js-and-hello-world)

Comment: Anytime. Enjoy it! ;-)